# mass import .csv files into postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy

i am using Postgresql 9.4 and trying to import all files in a specific folder into and existing table using the following command:

```
COPY xxx_table FROM '/filepath/filename_*.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

marking * as a variable part of the file name.

However it results in an error. I have found similar question on here however non of them is related to "COPY" command or alternatively using psql.

Any help on this would be highly appriciated.

Comment: When  trying to upload multiple files using above COPY script i am getting an error "file not available", probably because sql does not recognize a wildcard character "*" before ".csv".

Answer (score -1):

Do you need first `create` the `table` manually, then:

Copy data from your CSV file to the table:

**Example:**

```
\copy zip_codes FROM '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

You can also specify the columns to read:

**Example:**

```
\copy zip_codes(ZIP,CITY,STATE) FROM '/path/to/csv/ZIP_CODES.txt' DELIMITER ',' CSV
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, alessadro. How would i need to modify the above sql in case in i have 3 ZIP_CODES.txt files in the same location, i.e.: ZIP_CODE_1.txt, ZIP_CODE_2.txt, ZIP_CODE_3.txt. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, is all are the "same" type, merge them in only one file, or execute three times the command (changing the filepath).